# How to call a controller function from a user made library in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, libraries, controllers

okay to explain the problem. I have a controller function that is called DeleteBookPage. When this function is called it gets all the data needed for the DeleteBook page. Once on the page the user selects the data they want to delete off their profiles and calls one of my library functions that does the deleting. Now in the library I want to call the DeleteBookPage function in my controller so that I can reload the DeleteBook page with out the old items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not clear exactly how you are calling your DeleteBookPage method, eg. whether it is called directly through the URI or through another method. But essentially all you need to to do is make a route to the DeleteBookPage method and redirect the browser to that URI.

```
redirect('/controller/DeleteBookPage');
```

The only issue is that your libraries should really work independently, i.e. they shouldn't rely on a particular route being set up to function properly. This easy to do if your uri is already pointing to the DeleteBookPage method because you can just refresh the current page:

```
redirect($this->uri->uri_string());
```

If this is not the case, you could store the path to the controller in a config file and redirect to it that way or just return true on success of your library function and the redirect or refresh from your controller.

Hope this is clear, ask if you need mor info.

**NOTE**
You will need the uri helper loaded for the above to work.

Comment: This is exactly what I did using the redirect. It worked perfectly but thank you so much for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Well a good way you may use if this library has your CRUD functions

in your library constructor do the following

var $contr

public function __construct($params=array()) {

```
    $this->ci =& get_instance();
    $this->ci->load->helper('url');
    $this->controller=$this->ci->uri->segment(2);

}
```